# Swift 3.0 Extension - Methods are not getting called in Child class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, extension-methods

I have an Extension implementation problem when I am converting my code from swift 2.3 to swift 3.0.
Problem statement: -

**1) Each inherited class asking for protocol implementation**

**2) Not able to call methods which are already implemented in Extension.**

Please check below code for more understanding.

```
  protocol MyExtension {
        static func addTwoNumber(number1: Double, number2: Double)
    }

    extension MyExtension {
        static func addTwoNumber(number1: Double, number2: Double) {
          //implementation
      }

        static func subTractTwoNumbers(number1: Double, number2: Double) {
         //implementation
      }
    }

    internal class firstClass: MyExtension {
         static func multiplyTwoNumbers(number1: Double, number2: Double) {
        //implementation
        // if I call subTractTwoNumbers in this class it is giving me an error    
          subTractTwoNumbers(10, 10)
        //and asking me to implement protocol method as well ie 
        //static func addTwoNumber(number1: Double, number2: Double)
      }
    }
```

Please let me know, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Always use xcode suggestion for using property and methods. there might be issue in writing func properly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
subTractTwoNumbers(10, 10)
```

With

```
subTractTwoNumbers(number1: 10, number2: 10) // you must have to pass the argument lables name to call the function.
```

If you don’t want an argument label for a parameter, write an underscore (_) instead of an explicit argument label for that parameter

```
static func subTractTwoNumbers(_: Double, _: Double) {
 //implementation
}
```

Also, you have written one extra curly braces at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The above code was just the prototype for explaining my problem. I got the problem. My return type of prototype's method was Request and the method which I implemented in extension was  DataRequest. That's why it was showing me the error.

Comment: This code doesn't produce the protocol implementation error. Glad to hear you got the problem. And always put the same prototype code.

Answer (score 0):

Write function in extension as below

```
 extension MyExtension {


     func addTwoNumber(number1: Double, number2: Double) {
          //implementation
      }

        func subTractTwoNumbers(number1: Double, number2: Double) {
         //implementation
      }
        }
```